# 1822, "Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint in referenced table script

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, mysql-workbench

```
create table TruckMake(
TruckMakeID char(3) NOT NULL,
TruckMakeName varchar(20) NOT NULL,
primary key (TruckMakeID));

create table TruckModel(
TruckMakeID char(3) NOT NULL,
TruckModelID char(3) NOT NULL,
TruckModelName varchar(5) NOT NULL,
primary key (TruckMakeID, TruckModelID),
foreign key (TruckMakeID) references TruckMake(TruckMakeID));

create table Truck(
TruckVINNum char(4) NOT NULL,
TruckMakeID char(3) NOT NULL,
TruckModelID char(3) NOT NULL,
TruckColour varchar(15) NOT NULL,
TruckPurchaseDate date NOT NULL,
TruckCost decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
primary key (TruckVINNum),
constraint truck_ibfk_2 foreign key (TruckMakeID) references TruckModel(TruckMakeID),
constraint truck_ibfk_1 foreign key (TruckModelID) references TruckModel(TruckModelID));
```

The error i'm getting is:

01:19:32    create table Truck( TruckVINNum char(4) NOT NULL, TruckMakeID char(3) NOT NULL, TruckModelID char(3) NOT NULL, TruckColour varchar(15) NOT NULL, TruckPurchaseDate date NOT NULL, TruckCost decimal(8,2) NOT NULL, primary key (TruckVINNum), constraint truck_ibfk_2 foreign key (TruckMakeID) references TruckModel(TruckMakeID),

```
constraint truck_ibfk_1 foreign key (TruckModelID) references TruckModel(TruckModelID)) 
Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint.  
   Missing index for constraint 'truck_ibfk_1' in the referenced table 'truckmodel' 0.000 sec
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: Nothing changed since [your previous question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/301636/1822-failed-to-add-the-foreign-key-constraint-missing-index-for-constraint-in).

Comment: Add `INDEX(TruckModelID)` to `TruckModel`

Comment: @Akina - Let's let that one die; this one has enough to tackle the question.

Comment: thank you for your help. I did this:
create table TruckModel(
TruckMakeID char(3) NOT NULL,
TruckModelID char(3) NOT NULL,
TruckModelName varchar(5) NOT NULL,
Index(TruckModelID),
primary key (TruckMakeID, TruckModelID),
foreign key (TruckMakeID) references TruckMake(TruckMakeID));

but the same error shows up

Answer (score 3):

The primary key of truckmodel is `primary key (TruckMakeID, TruckModelID)`

So you can't reference `TruckModel(TruckModelID))`.

You could have:

```
foreign key (TruckMakeID, TruckModelID) 
    references TruckModel (TruckMakeID, TruckModelID)
```

Comment: (syntax error)...

Comment: @RickJames  Thanks, long live cut and paste.

Comment: Thank you so much!